# When to use method sync() for elmongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have to implement a full text search with Elasticsearch, having MongoDB at persistance layer, and the application is on Node.js. I'm using `elmongo` library for that.

According to the [tutorial](http://www.usesold.com/blog/2013/08/06/In-2-Minutes-from-Zero-to-elasticsearch-with-Mongoose.html) I have to call

```
     Cat.sync(function (err) {
      // all cats are now searchable in elasticsearch
    })
```

in order to add my existing data to search index.

The question is:

When do I have to call this method, so that if I add more "Cats" I will still have them in Elasticsearch search index? Can you explain me the process of how the data is added to search index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in the [documentation](https://github.com/usesold/elmongo/blob/master/readme.md) of `elmongo`.

> Re-indexes your collection's data in Elasticsearch. After the first `.sync()` call, Elasticsearch will be all setup with your collection's data. You can re-index your data anytime using this function. Re-indexing is done with zero downtime, so you can keep making search queries even while `.sync()` is running, and your existing data will be searchable.

As I can conclude from that, the `.sync()` has to be done after the documents in are created/updated.